# Rails getting data inside an ActiveRecord object which is inside an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Ok, convoluted title, I know, but the situation is the following:

I have a query (`failed_by_apps = Search.failed_by_app`) that returns something like this:

```
s.each_with_index { |item, i| puts "index: #{i} item: #{item}" }
index: 0 item: #<Search:0x007faf858da068>
index: 1 item: #<Search:0x007faf858d9cd0>
index: 2 item: #<Search:0x007faf858d9960>
index: 3 item: #<Search:0x007faf858d95a0>
```

Each of the search items is an ActiveRecord item which contains something like this:

```
s.each { |item| puts "#{item.app}: #{item.appFailed}"  }
book: 23885
dvd: 9563
cd: 4850
game: 629
```

The problem comes when I try to get the value of appFailed without doing a .each loop. See, I have another bit of code where I want to put together information from different queries into one hash, it looks like this:

```
i = 0
appTotals.each do |app| 
    @appHash[app.app] =  {"appTotal" => app.appTotal, "percent" => failed_by_apps[i].appFailed }   
    i += 1  
end
```

This works, but I'm thinking there must surely be a better (more elegant) way of doing this no?

**Edit:**
Please ignore former question about math, I just want to figure out a better way to get the value inside failed_by_apps[x].appFailed

Comment: I'm a bit lost. What's `appTotals`? How does it relate to `failed_by_apps`? What are you ultimately trying to achieve - filling `@appHash` with... what?

Comment: You will have to excuse me, my crystal ball is a bit shady today, who is `appTotals` again ? And what does it have to do with apps failed by  something? So what are you trying to achieve (in words) ? Maybe [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) are of interest ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter what appTotals is, (it's the sum of all those numbers spit out in the second block of code). What I'm trying to figure out is how to access the values inside this array `failed_by_apps[i].appFailed` in a better fashion. I've figured out the math bit so please ignore that.

Comment: So, `failed_by_apps` contains a set of database records, each of which contains `app` (string) and `appFailed` (integer); and you want to get `appFailed` for each entry... without using `each` or an `i` index? You want to stuff the `appFailed` values into something else? I think we're close to being able to help, but things are just a little hazy still.

Comment: @Chowlett that is correct. Exactly what I want. Like I said above, it works this way, but I think there's a better way to to it no?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little confused as to *exactly* what you want, but hopefully we can get there be progressive refinement. How about this is a starting point?

```
failed_by_apps.map(&:appFailed)
# => [23885, 9563, 4850, 629]
```